# Remove Keyboard Focus Rect From FlipView Control in Windows Store App

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Does anyone know how to remove the keyboard focus rect that appears in a FlipView Control when you use the cursor keys to navigate left and right?

I thought I could just set the FocusVisualStyle to null but that doesn't seem to be a supported property in WinRT.

Surely there must be some way to hide that annoying dotted outline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually worked out how to remove the focus rect by creating the following Style using Blend and remove the storyboards that set the FocusVisual elements. I've included the full style below in case it of use to anyone else.

```
<Style x:Key="NoFocusFlipViewStyle" TargetType="FlipView">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel AreScrollSnapPointsRegular="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlipView">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="3">
                        <Border.Resources>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalNextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M4.12,0 L9.67,5.47 L4.12,10.94 L0,10.88 L5.56,5.47 L0,0.06 z" Fill="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="10.94" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9.67"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalPreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M5.55,0 L9.67,0.06 L4.12,5.47 L9.67,10.88 L5.55,10.94 L0,5.48 z" Fill="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="10.94" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9.67"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalNextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0.06,0 L5.47,5.56 L10.88,0 L10.94,4.12 L5.48,9.67 L0,4.12 z" Fill="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="9.67" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10.94"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalPreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M5.63,0 L11.11,5.55 L11.05,9.67 L5.64,4.12 L0.23,9.67 L0.17,5.55 z" Fill="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="9.67" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10.94"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Border.Resources>
                        <Grid>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollingHost" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <Button x:Name="PreviousButtonHorizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalPreviousTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70"/>
                            <Button x:Name="NextButtonHorizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalNextTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70"/>
                            <Button x:Name="PreviousButtonVertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource VerticalPreviousTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70"/>
                            <Button x:Name="NextButtonVertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource VerticalNextTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="70"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

That annoying dotted outline must be there precisely so you can navigate with your keyboard. You can restyle it or remove it by editing the template of the FlipView control and the buttons inside of it.

Comment: I realize that, but in my app the Flipview is not full screen and is the only element that requires keyboard navigation so not only does the focus rect look out of place, but it is completely redundant.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I can remove the Focus Rect from the Flip View using by setting its Style? I cannot see any valid property such as the FocusVisualStyle